PyQt6 TableView not displaying float32 numbers
I am populating my TableView with pandas DataFrame. My DataFrame has 6 columns, 5 columns are of type String and 6th column is of type float32. The problem is TableView is not displaying values of 6th column (float32), so esentially it's blank. However data is there, because when I debug and press column header to sort column i can see data is there (just isn't displayed).
I need my 6th column to stay float32 so I can sort it numerically as opposed to other columns that are sorted alphanumerically and I want values of this column to be displayed properly as well. Here is the code I have:
main.py:
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return value #here returning values as they are so 5 columns strings 6th one float

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#setting up my model df is pandas DataFrame
model = TableModel(df)
#create sorter model
sortermodel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
sortermodel.setSourceModel(model)
ui.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
#passing model to tableview (will not work if I remove tableview element from UI designer)
ui.tableView.setModel(sortermodel)
MainWindow.show()
app.exec()

MainWindow.py:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-5, 1, 671, 511))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.downloadTodaysData = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.downloadTodaysData.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 20, 75, 24))
        self.downloadTodaysData.setObjectName("downloadTodaysData")
        self.LoadData = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.LoadData.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 50, 75, 24))
        self.LoadData.setObjectName("LoadData")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 80, 75, 24))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.LastDataLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.LastDataLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 0, 121, 20))
        self.LastDataLabel.setObjectName("LastDataLabel")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tableView.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.downloadTodaysData.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Get Data"))
        self.LoadData.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load Data"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ChartingDatatodo"))
        self.LastDataLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Last Data:"))


PyQt "communicates" with Qt by converting compatible types from Python ones to C++ ones, but that only works for standard Python types (eg: float). float32 is a numpy type, therefore you need to convert it into a suitable type. Just add an if isinstance(value, numpy.float32): value = float(value) before returning, or convert it only if it belongs to a column you know only contains float numbers. (You obviously need to import numpy for that)

return value.item() if index.column() == 5 else value.
